# While loop insert into table with CTE's (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, syntax, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Correct Snowflake syntax for the below:

```
execute immediate $$ 
declare
  end_period int default 10;
  start_period int default 0;
 
begin 
  while ($start_period < $end_period ) do  

    with cte_example as (
       select 
          account_id, 
          sum(sales) as sales
       from table
       where period <= $end_period 
       group by account_id
    )
    insert into target_table (account_id, sales)
    select account_id, sales
    from cte_example

    end_period := end_period  + 1;
  end while;
end;
$$
```

I'm wanting to do a while loop in Snowflake inserting into a table each iteration

Comment: Did you mean to have current_period rather than end_period in your DECLARE section?

Comment: Fixed to only use start_period and end_period

Comment: Ok - so what’s the actual issue now? For example, does your code error (what’s the error), does it not give the result you want (what does it do), or what?

Comment: Also looping is generally "bad" in a database, and almost anything (beside recursion) achievable in loops can be done in relational algebra, you might do better to swap the task over to this style of thinking.

Comment: Current error is unexpected 'as' right after 'with cte_example'

Comment: the WITH binds to the SELECT not the INSERT so the code should be `INSERT INTO ... WITH name as (...) SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Now that I reformatted you SQL to read what it does, you should use a [generator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator) to form you `10-0 = 10` rows, and use a `row_number() over (order by null) -1` to give you row numbers, then you can use this as a WHERE clause (again via a join) and then once you have the correct set of row, just insert these, in one operation. You will want to group by the rn number after the joins so that you sub-totals are correct.

so the first part was:

```
with fake_sales(account_id, period, sales) as (
    select * from values
        (100,  1, 11),
        (100,  2, 12),
        (100,  3, 13)
), gens as (
    select row_number() over(order by null) as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>10))
)
select *
from gens as g
join fake_sales as s
    on s.period <= g.rn
```

[image]

now to aggregate:

```
with fake_sales(account_id, period, sales) as (
    select * from values
        (100,  1, 11),
        (100,  2, 12),
        (100,  3, 13)
), gens as (
    select row_number() over(order by null) as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>10))
)
select account_id, 
    sum(sales) as sales
from gens as g
join fake_sales as s
    on s.period <= g.rn
group by s.account_id, g.rn
order by 1
```

[image]

the problem with your SQL is this is WITH binds to the SELECT not the INSERT thus you want:

```
insert into target_table (account_id, sales)
    with cte_example as (
       select 
          account_id, 
          sum(sales) as sales
       from table
       where period <= $end_period 
       group by account_id
    )
    select account_id, sales
    from cte_example
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Seems like a cool potential solution. I'll have to try it out Monday.

Comment: You this code is doing, is the steps of the loop in one step. This is how you get performance. If you learn how to think this way, the database will become very simple to dance with.

Comment: I will have to follow this up with that the actual 'periods' are not as easy as 0-10. They are periodID's in the form of YYYYMM. This case when will add iterate these correctly: case when substring(cast($periodid as varchar),5,2) = 12 then $periodid + 89 else $periodid + 1 end
How would I implement this into your code?

Comment: You can put any logic you like into a CTE to preprocess from value space X to value space Y. The whole point is change from line at a time transforms and lookups. To seeing what are the big picture results needed to be built up so they large volume data can  tranformed in the most efficient manor. And then join those built up data on the smallest sets of resultants. Because per row processing does not scale well and joins are expensive. Aka performance cone from being less. In fact the least that still gets the desired result.